# android Activity is declered on Manifest but exceptions says it is not

Tags: android, android-activity

I have worked with activities many times, but I don't know why is this exception happened,
I want to start activity when a user clicks on a button , but i got exception says that I haven't declare this activity on `Manifest` but i did,

#### Mainfest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Address"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Are you sure your Activity is in the right package?

Comment: Are you sure that you are Using your activity class (Address.class) and not (Android.Location.Address.class) ?

Comment: @RaghavSood yes all in the same package,

Comment: @Mr.Me yes ofcouse, I give you the code , It is on the `onclick`

Comment: @user2059935 try once without the dot in ".Address"..

Comment: try once with full package name like com.package_name.file_name

Comment: @Nezam do u mean on manifest ?

Comment: yes you put that in manifiest

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj you are maject, it works , please tell me why is adding the full package path is make it work ? i always don't add the full package and it works

Comment: Use full activity package qualifier in your manifest:
android:name="your.package.Address"

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj write it as an asnnwer, i will accept it

Comment: Have you got the code for the onActivityResult. I think that is where the issue nothing to do with how its declared in the manifest

Comment: @Boardy i got an answer from Tamilaras

Comment: Because some times you are add more than one packages in the running time this type of error will be display..

Comment: Also simply 

 <activity
            android:name="Address"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

would have worked

Comment: @user2059935 for the sake of testing just test it works or not.. and inform me

Comment: @Nezam yes you right too

Comment: @user2059935 for the sake of testing just test it works or not.. and inform me Sorry i didn't get clearly please explain

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj be honest,did my comment direct you to your present comment which solved it.lol!

Comment: yes i got that but best way to put the full package name is always because this avoid duplicates between the packages

Comment: and you too post your answer for your question that will useful for future vistors.

Comment: no its okay.You were more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Try once with full package name like

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.package_name.file_name "
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```